# Add ibanCode to exceptionMessage

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I want to add iban code to my `OpaCallException`, so that I would know specifically which iban code is incorrect. 
My code:

```
 FIND FIRST tt_iban_crc_aaa WHERE tt_iban_crc_aaa.iban=tt_fee_request.debtorAccount AND tt_iban_crc_aaa.crc=g-crc NO-LOCK NO-ERROR.
IF NOT AVAILABLE tt_iban_crc_aaa THEN DO:
     FIND FIRST aaa WHERE aaa.name=tt_fee_request.debtorAccount AND aaa.crc=g-crc NO-LOCK NO-ERROR.
     IF AVAILABLE aaa THEN DO:
         CREATE tt_iban_crc_aaa.
         ASSIGN
            tt_iban_crc_aaa.aaa   = aaa.aaa
            tt_iban_crc_aaa.crc = aaa.crc
            tt_iban_crc_aaa.iban = aaa.name
            .
     END.
     ELSE DO:
         UNDO, THROW NEW OpaCallException("iban.invalid", "Iban incorrect", "Provided iban is invalid").
     END.
END.
```

I am having difficult time with progress syntax. I could use some help or tips, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to use the SUBSTITUTE() function.

Replace "Provided iban is invalid" with SUBSTITUTE ("Provided iban (&1) is invalid", [Whatever field the iban code is in]).

Comment: Isn't there any basic solution like `OpaCallException("iban.invalid", "Iban incorrect"+iban, "Provided iban is invalid").` ? I'm just not familiar with the syntax of progress, I want to add the iban variable to the errorMessage

Comment: You can use + to concatenate, but if the iban is unknown then the whole expression becomes unknown. The SUBSTITUTE() function gets around this issue. Also, if the iban is not a charatcer you have to cast it, which again SUSBTITUTE circumvents.

Comment: You can concatenate strings using the + operator. Is iban Character or integer? SUBSTITUTE has benefits. If  any part of the + expression is ? (unknown) + returns ? for the whole. SUBSTITUTE is safer there.

Comment: @jdpjamesp The ABL does not support CAST on primitive types. The STRING function does actually convert - duplicates the data.

Comment: @MikeFechner you are right about CAST (), but I was using cast in the general term (hence lower case!), as the STRING () function casts a value to a string datatype.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a property in your OpaCallException class

```
DEFINE PUBLIC PROPERTY IbanCode AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO 
GET.
PRIVATE SET .
```

Then add a constructor like this:

```
CONSTRUCTOR PUBLIC OpaCallException (pcIbanCode AS CHARACTER, /* add additional parameters */):

    ASSIGN THIS-OBJECT:IbanCode = pcIbanCode. 

    SUPER (SUBSTITUTE ("Error with IBAN Code: &1", pcIbanCode), 0) . 

END CONSTRUCTOR.
```